# partial match for FILTER function in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

i have this formula

```
=QUERY(FILTER('US Books Rebounds'!$D$2:$N$1500,'US Books Rebounds'!$D$2:$D$1500="DraftKings",'US Books Rebounds'!$I$2:$I$1500="Over",'US Books Rebounds'!$J$2:$J$1500=B11),"select Col8")
```

B11=Nic Claxton

however in "US Book Rebounds" its spelled Nicolas Claxton

This happens with a few players but the last name is always correct. how can i adjust the above formula to match last names?

Comment: are the last names unique?

Comment: Yes, all names of players, spelling varies from dataset to dataset but last name is always the same..

Comment: I mean if the last names are unique, i.e. there aren't different players with the same last name.

Comment: oh man good thinking yes,  im sure there are last names in common  ie. "Smith" "Jones" etc     maybe first intial and lastname something like that...thanks for your time

Comment: some names also have jr.

Comment: can you share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)? It would be easier to test potential solutions.

Comment: sure  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GBd-qqkwRE5Qifib8lpDP2AX8pGH8FXECdiaGtxbaAE/edit?usp=sharing        Issue can be seen in row 11 however as mentioned there are names that have jr at the end.. along with some players with matching lastnames... thanks

Comment: looking over the nba rosters, i think if everything past the second space of the string is dropped, then match the first letter of the string and the last name.. this seems to be a good solution.. im pretty bad with regex tho,, maybe i can make a helper sheet that does thie formatting before the final rebound sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `[FIRST_INITIAL] [LAST_NAME]`  are unique, you can use [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) to turn the names into that format:

```cpp
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(^.| .+)|.","$1")
```

[image]

If `[FIRST_INITIAL] [LAST_NAME]` are not unique, you can replace `[FIRST_INITAL]` with `[FIRST_N_INITALS]`, like so:

```cpp
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(^..| .+)|.","$1") or =REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(^.{2}| .+)|.","$1")
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(^...| .+)|.","$1") or =REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(^.{3}| .+)|.","$1")
```

[image]

The formula you proposed is also valid. The advantage of this formula over the one you proposed is that you don't need to write che cell reference twice.

Comment: thank you, yours is much cleaner. you have helped me a lot with this project. i really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

My Solution

```
=UPPER(CONCATENATE(LEFT(A3,1)," ",INDEX(SPLIT(A3, " "),2)))
```